Dynamically generated mPDF pdf file from ajax call with wrong file extension
I am dynamically generating a pdf from a page's html using mPDF called with ajax. The issue is, though the pdf opens in a new window, the filename ends up being my mPDF php file, open-pdf.php, instead of the filename I gave to mPDF inside open-pdf.php, news.pdf. I assume this is because of the way that I am opening the pdf through a link in JS, but don't know how else to do it. This is all based in a plugin on a WordPress site.
The relevant JS:
// the "article" var is a WordPress post number, 18861 for example
// the "url" var is the link my mPDF generating php, basically www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/includes/templates/open-pdf.php
var pdfAjaxCall = function (article, url) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: 'getting_html',
                    article: article,
                },
                url: my.ajaxurl,
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = response.slice(0, -1);;
                    if (data.length > 1) {
                        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                        var iOS = !!ua.match(/iP(ad|od|hone)/i);
                        var webkit = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);
                        var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i) && !ua.match(/OPiOS/i);
                        console.log('is iOS Safari', iOSSafari)
                        // if (iOSSafari && !$(".popup-overlay[article='"+ article +"'], .popup-content[article='"+ article +"']").hasClass("active")) {
                        //     $(".popup-overlay[article='"+ article +"'], .popup-content[article='"+ article +"']").addClass("active");
                        // }
                        console.log('pdf ajax response', data)
                        $.post(url, { data: data }, function () {
                            var link = document.createElement('a');
                            link.href = url;
                            link.target = '_blank';
                            if (iOSSafari && !$(".popup-overlay[article='" + article + "'], .popup-content[article='" + article + "']").hasClass("active")) {
                                $("a.generated-link[article='" + article + "']").attr('href', url);
                                $(".popup-overlay[article='" + article + "'], .popup-content[article='" + article + "']").addClass("active");
                            } else {
                                document.body.appendChild(link);
                                link.click();
                                document.body.removeChild(link);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Ajax response is empty.');
                    }
                }
            });
        };

The open-pdf.php file:
<?php

session_start();
ob_clean();
// DO NOT just copy from _POST to _SESSION,
// as it could allow a malicious user to override security.
// Use a disposable variable key, such as "data" here.
if (array_key_exists('data', $_POST)) {
    // if (array_key_exists('ts', $_POST)) {
        // TODO: verify ts(), but beware of time zones!
        $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];
        // Header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    // Header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
    // Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='news.pdf';");
        die(json_encode(array('status' => 'OK')));
    // }
    die("Error");
}
// This is safe (we move unsecurity-ward):
$my_html = $_SESSION['data'];
unset($_SESSION['data']); // keep things clean.

require_once('../../mpdf-8.1.0/vendor/autoload.php');
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
// $mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=1;
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
// $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
//     <div style="width: 100%; height: 0.8in; overflow:hidden;">
//         <div style="padding-top: 0.15in; padding-bottom: 0.2in; float:right;">
//             <p style="color: #212559; font-size: 13px; margin-left:580px;">Kiernantrebach.cloudorpheus.com</p>
//         </div>
//     </div>
// ');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($my_html);
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='news.pdf';");
// $mpdf->Output('news.pdf', 'D');
$mpdf->Output("news.pdf", "I");
exit;
/*
//Set Your Options -- we are saving the PDF as 'my_filename.pdf' to a 'my_pdfs' folder
$pdf_options = array(
  "source_type" => 'html',
  "source" => $my_html,
  "action" => 'save',
  "save_directory" => 'my_pdfs',
  "file_name" => 'my_filename.pdf');

//Code to generate PDF file from options above
phptopdf($pdf_options);
*/
?>

I need the pdf to open in a new tab, which it currently does, but also properly download as a pdf, which it currently does not. I know that the $mpdf->Output("news.pdf", "I"); line in the php file is supposed to do what I need, and it was previously just $mpdf->Output(); before I tried adding the filename and "I" to fix my issue, and I am very confused why that isn't working considering that changing that "I" to "D" immediately downloads the pdf with the correct filename without opening the pdf in a new tab, as expected - but that isn't what I need!
EDIT:
The pdfAjaxCall function is called from an on click listener:
if ($('.generate-pdf').length > 0) {
            const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const article = param.get('news_release');
            var url = my.siteurl + "/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/includes/templates/open-pdf.php";

            $("#pdf-button").on('click', function (e) {
                pdfAjaxCall(article, url);
            });

            $(".close[article='" + article + "'], .popup-overlay[article='" + article + "']").on("click", function (e) {
                $(".popup-overlay[article='" + article + "'], .popup-content[article='" + article + "']").removeClass("active");
            });
        }

The generated link that is clicked at the end of the callback correctly opens the pdf in a new window (when the mPDF Output destination is inline) but downloads as open-pdf.php - the link that the pdf opens at is also www.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/includes/templates/open-pdf.php (exact site url and plugin name changed for anonymity).
The client wants the #pdf-button to open the pdf in a new window, and allow users to then download that pdf if they so wish, and not download it if they don't.

why do you want to download the file in a new tab ? edit your question to add more details about the aim of your code and we could better advice you. e.g. it's certainly possible to generate the pdf file with a single http request instead of two.

So you are making a POST request to url first, to set some session values, and then you are making a GET request for that same URL, via the automatically clicked link. Would probably make more sense, if you eliminated the AJAX part, and instead submitted a form with target="_blank", to send your POST parameters, and then have the script respond with the resulting PDF directly.

@mmm The primary function of the code is to open a pdf for users to view in a new tab. They should also be able to download this pdf if they wish, but that is second after viewing. Currently, they cannot download a pdf, only a php file. The html being given to mPDF is generated from the 'getting_html' action in the first request. To summarize the aim, I suppose it would be to generate html for any 'article' and use that html to generate a pdf, then open that pdf in a new tab, and allow users to download the pdf in that new tab if they wish.

@C3roe I will look into this, but I assume you're talking about the second AJAX part - the first AJAX request is necessary to generate the html that mPDF is using. Would you be willing to write up an answer for this?

if the action getting_html is on the same server, you juste have to call it in php, you don't need to make a first http request in javascript to retrieve data.

Why those two steps to begin with? Why isn't this a one-step process that generates the HTML code first, and then immediately passes it on to the PDF generator?

If you really want to keep doing it in this rather inefficient way - then setting the download attribute on the link you are creating there, to the desired filename, should also work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download (Assuming this is all same-origin.)

I really would prefer to not do it in this inefficient way, but this is a fix for a client's live production wordpress site, and I'm not familiar enough with php and mPDF to make major changes to the JS and mPDF implementation on the fly - I'm trying to set up a development environment for testing, but in the meantime, I've just changed $mpdf->Output("news.pdf", "I"); to $mpdf->Output("news.pdf", "D"); and am having the pdfs download directly instead of open in a new window. This is not what my client ultimately wants, but has accepted it as a temporary fix.

Unfortunately the download attribute on the link doesn't fix the issue - in fact, it doesn't even overwrite the "news.pdf" filename from mPDF. With $mpdf->Output("news.pdf", "I"); and a download attribute of news-release.pdf the file downloads as news.pdf. So, I've just omitted the download attribute for now and am sticking with $mpdf->Output("news.pdf", "D"); which does the same thing. @C3roe
